# In Robo Rally, do robots that get pushed onto a conveyor by a pusher also move via conveyor?

Tags: robo-rally

If a pusher pushes me onto a conveyor belt, do I then apply the movement of the belt on my robot as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order of board element movement is in the [rules (page 6)](https://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/roborally.pdf).

1. Express conveyor belts move 1 space in the direction of the arrows.
2. Express conveyor belts and normal conveyor belts move 1 space in the direction of the arrows.
3. Pushers push if active.
4. Gears rotate 90° in the direction of the arrows.

The belt moves first. So if you are pushed on the belt, you are not also moved because it has already moved this phase.

Comment: It's also in the top right corner of the program sheet that each player gets.